# Simplify a php function whitch use FileMaker API

Tags: php, arrays, function, filemaker, simplify

I use the FileMaker API PHP to take FileMaker data in php.
So, it works very well. I would like to simplify it.

```
/** This code is correct and can't modify ***/
require_once ('inc/FM/FileMaker.php');
require_once ('inc/FM/param_FM.php');
$modele="Mura";
$id_folder=$_GET["folder"];
$id_ouvrage=$_GET["id"];
$findCommand =& $base->newFindCommand($modele);
$findCommand ->addFindCriterion('ID OUVRAGE', $id_ouvrage);
$result = $findCommand->execute();
if (!FileMaker::isError($result)) {
    $records = $result->getRecords();
}
else{
    echo "No result";
}
/*** END unmodify code ***/
```

When I want to show some data I use this :

```
$Collection  = $records[0]->getField('Collection book');
$title = $records[0]->getField('Title book');
$years = $records[0]->getField('Years book');
```

But I have all data in a array.

```
$data= array('Collection' => 'Collection book','Title' => 'Title book', 'years' => 'Years book');
```

I have 48 datas like this.
Can I use this array to simplify all data?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if it's what you're asking for, and it doesn't make too much sense if you actually have only three fields, but you could do something like this:

```
foreach ( $data as $var => $field ) {
  $$var = $records[0]->getField( $field );
}
```

This will create a variable for each of the keys that you have in your array. With the `$data` you provided, it will create `$Collection` set to `'Collection book'`, `$Title` set to `'Title book'` and `$years` set to `'Years book'`. Note the capitalization of the variable names because two of the keys in your array are capitalized.